# How do I get a party of heroes interested enough to attack monsters?

Tags: majesty-2

By the end of most scenarios I have some pretty high level heroes. Mostly warriors, dwarves and mages - and a few specials like blademasters and paladins. When I create parties using the inn, I group  2 to 3 high damage wariors/dwarves and have a warrior as the leader and a cleric for support. All in all a formidable force that can take down any high level monster on the map without too much trouble.

The problem is they never seem to be interested in going out and attacking them. I place bounties ranging from 2k to 4k but they don't seem interested. If the monster comes into my town (e.g. - in the scenario where you have to kill the dragon - Rafnir), they'll attack it but otherwise they'll just wander around the town and not go too far away.

Is my strategy wrong? Should I place a higher bounty? The monsters I'm talking about are the end game ones like the Lich and other high level ones. But I've also seen the same behavior where they simply ignore easier monsters like high level Elementals that are relatively far away from the town.

Any suggestions on how I can get them to be more hero like?

I have the base version of the game by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an end-level boss I often put bounties of up to 10k gold, but really a 5k bounty should get many of your groups interested.

One thing that also helps is to build the Statue of the King - it makes your heroes go after lower bounties than they would otherwise.

You might try making a new guild and get some low level rogues/warriors/rangers and make them party leaders.  They may get one-shotted but they'll get your high level heroes into the battle.  I haven't tried this but it seems like it might work.

Comment: +1 Hmm, the lower level ones dragging them along sounds like a good idea. Never knew that the Statue of the King had that effect. I'll try out the ideas when I get home, thanks for the tips.

Comment: also: different leaders follow different flags more eagerly. Elves -> exploration. Knights -> attack. etc

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that the distance between a monster and the location of the hero is important. if you build a guild near the place where you need your heros, they will more likely go there. used this when attacking the elemental lord before he became a demigod in monster kingdom.